# The sides of a spoon as concave/convex mirrors

Tags: optics, geometric-optics, lenses, photonics

I recently saw a lecture that said the following regarding the sides of a spoon as concave/convex mirrors:

> 1. The concave inside of the spoon must be a positive focal length mirror because it would take normally incident rays and bend them towards the axis.
> 2. Conversely, the convex outside of the spoon must be a negative focal length mirror because it bends rays away from the axis.

I immediately found this perplexing, since my understanding is that it precisely is the *opposite*. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lens#Types_of_simple_lenses) (seemingly) agrees with me and says the following:

> If the lens is biconvex or plano-convex, a collimated beam of light passing through the lens converges to a spot (a *focus*) behind the lens. In this case, the lens is called a *positive* or *converging* lens. For a thin lens in air, the distance from the lens to the spot is the focal length of the lens, which is commonly represented by $f$ in diagrams and equations.
>
> If the lens is biconcave or plano-concave, a collimated beam of light passing through the lens is diverged (spread); the lens is thus called a *negative* or *diverging* lens. The beam, after passing through the lens, appears to emanate from a particular point on the axis in front of the lens. For a thin lens in air, the distance from this point to the lens is the focal length, though it is negative with respect to the focal length of a converging lens.

Am I misunderstanding or misinterpreting something here?

I would greatly appreciate it if people could please take the time to clarify this.

Comment: You are mixing up mirrors and lenses.  Look up concave and convex mirrors instead of lenses.

Comment: @BillWatts I understand. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first quote deals with a mirror lens, reflection, the second quote refers to light passing through a clear lens, refraction.

Comment: edited, reflection verses refraction

Comment: I understand. Thanks for the clarification. Explained further here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curved_mirror#Analysis